# Ghostscript ps2pdf output size 555 points x 555 points

Tags: ghostscript, tex-live

I'm using ghostscript via TexLive command line. I need a PDF of size 555 x 555 points. I tried

```
ps2pdf rho.eps dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=555 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=555 myTest1.pdf
```

but it returned

```
Producer:       GPL Ghostscript 9.18
CreationDate:   10/31/16 21:29:18
ModDate:        10/31/16 21:29:18
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      612 x 555 pts (rotated 0 degrees)
File size:      2373 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set `-dFIXEDMEDIA`, if you don't do that, then the media size from the input will override the existing values. In effect you are only setting the default, adding FIXEDMEDIA means it cannot be altered.

Given that the input is an EPS file, it would almost certainly be better to **not** set DEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS and DEVICEWIDTHPOINTS and FIXEDMEDIA, but instead use `-dEPSCrop` which will set the media size to the BoundingBox defined in the EPS file.

If you actually want to scale the content of the EPS file to a specific size, then you will need to write a PostScript wrapper for the EPS.

Comment: The   '-dEPSCrop' flag solved the problem. For the reference of other on the forum, I was using .eps files generated by Maple, and it seems as though they specify 555x555 point by default.